# How to call void non static function by ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, function, non-static

How to call a non static void function from ajax.I am getting a error.
This is ajax code:-

```
    $('#button2 button').click(function () {

              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "practiced_final.aspx/display",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function () 
                {
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert(a + b + c);
                }
            })
                                return false;

           });
```

This is C# method code:

```
      [WebMethod]
 protected  void display()
    {

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "Hello");
    }
```

This is error message:-

```
[object XMLHttpRequest]errorundefined
```

What i am missing?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: add attribute to your method `display` `[Webmethod]`. I'm not sure if this method of yours should be public or not

Comment: i had already added it but didn't paste here.i still didn't work.
check updated code.

Comment: see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360253/call-non-static-method-in-server-sideaspx-cs-from-client-side-use-javascript] related question which should solve your question

Answer (score 2):

for it to work your function must be static, it should look like this:

```
[Webmethod]
public static void display()
{
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "Hello");
}
```

if you want your function to return a string you should change it to:

```
[Webmethod]
    public static string display()
    {
         return "Hello";
    }
```

Comment: it still gives error:-
[object XMLHttpRequest]parsererrorundefined

Comment: Maybe because the thing you return is not JSON.

Comment: you can't use HttpContext.Current.Response.Write in your function because it's void it shouldn't return any thing

Comment: @kleinohad
i use breakpoint.The control goes to the function but at its exit from body ,a alert box appears which says:_
[object XMLHttpRequest]parsererrorundefined

Comment: Then how can i print message if i can't use HttpContext.Current.Response.