# Redirecting to a page in asp.net using jquery with passing parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

How do I call a C# method in jquery script with passing parameters? 
I have a jquery accordion with icons implemented dynamically in code behind, once the user clicks the icon it should redirect to a certain page with passing parameter in the url. The data inside the accordion will be populated from the database and what I want to do is for example, when I click on the edit icon, it'd redirect to the editing page with the id of that specific record.

This is how my jQuery accordion looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Accordion code:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-lightbulb"></span></h3>
<div>
<p>
Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
</p>
</div>
```

An example of code when clicking the icon in jquery accordion:

```
$('span.ui-icon-lightbulb').click(function(e) {
    alert('Lightbulb');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It is similar to the following href functionality

```
<a href='EditRecord.aspx?recordID=" + record.ID + "'>Edit record</a>
```

but how to do it in jquery by passing the record id from asp.net c# code behind?

Comment: I'd recommend switching from postbacks to using jquery AJAX calls to get your content for the accordions.   You can then construct the URL as you like.    Look into ~$.ajax~ for jQuery.

Comment: P.S. My knowledge is limited when it comes to Ajax and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in the past using C# and static [Web Methods] with jQuery/Ajax. From what I remember the method had to be declared as a `public static` [WebMethod].

**For example:**

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static FooObj GetFooObj ()
 {
     // some code that returns FooObj 
 }
```

This thread may be of interest.

[ASP.NET calling non-static webmethod from JS AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500136/asp-net-calling-non-static-webmethod-from-js-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

I found another simple way of doing it, thanks anyway guys.

I'd post it just in case anyone needs it so here it is:
first of all, I set the ID of the span tag in code behind to the record's ID.
Then, I used `e.target.id` to get the id of the span element which in the previous step I set it to the record's ID. Finally, I used `var url = "EditRecord.aspx?recordID=" + e.target.id;
 $(location).attr('href', url);` to redirect to the edit page.

```
  <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion();
                $('span.ui-icon-pencil').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var url = "EditRecord.aspx?recordID=" + e.target.id;
                    $(location).attr('href', url);

                });
            });

   </script>
```