# WebMethod c# return double[]

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a WebMethod which return type is a double[]. I am trying to access this method in form but result is :

Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'FIR'. End element 'FIRResult' from namespace 'http://google.com/' expected. Found element 'double' from namespace 'http://google.com/'. Line 1, position 278.

Example code :

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int N = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int fN = int.Parse(textBox6.Text);
            int fS = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            int rippleLimit = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);

            double[] result = ws.FIR(N, (double)fN, (double)fS, rippleLimit);


            this.Hide();
        }


 [WebMethod]
        public double[] FIR(int N, double fs, double fn, int rippleLimit)
        {

            double rippleDev;
            List<double> result = new List<double>();

            List<double> signal = firDesign(N, fn, fs);
            DTFT(signal, N, fs, fn, 1);

            List<double> moduledSignal = moduleSignal(Service1.real, Service1.img);

            rippleDev = calculateRippleDev(fn, moduledSignal);

            result.Add(rippleDev);

        for (int i = 0; i < moduledSignal.Count; i++)
        {
            result.Add(moduledSignal[i]);
        }


        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the javascript call to the web method?

Answer (score 0):

Web methods need to be `static`, try:

```
[WebMethod]
public static double[] FIR(int N, double fs, double fn, int rippleLimit)
...
```

Comment: Are you sure? Microsoft uses `[WebMethod]` in a non-static context. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Odd, I need to read that link properly, but yes webmethods need to be static, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360253/call-non-static-method-in-server-sideaspx-cs-from-client-side-use-javascript

Comment: I think you/we are confusing WebServices with PageMethods, which are you trying to create? (both use the [WebMethod] attribute) We need to see more of your code, server side and client side.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with static but now it has this problem...
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://google.com/FIR.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)

in Form when i call the method web method

Comment: WE NEED TO SEE MORE CODE! How are you calling this method? Where is http://google.com coming from!?

Answer (score -1):

www.google.com is from namespace "[WebService(Namespace ]".