# How to make call of a Non-Static C# function on aspx page

Tags: asp.net

i want to call a c# function from aspx page i tried it like  below

```
 function  DeleteKartItems(callback) {

   $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'About.aspx/updatingdatabase',// my function name in c#
             data: '{"username":"' + col1 + '","password":"' + col2 + '","age":"' + col3 + '","city":"' + col4 + '","id":"' + idlast + '"}',
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                              var x = data.d;// i am trying to store the return data into a local variable

             },
             error: function (e) {

             }
         });

     }
```

my problem is its works fine when i write the c# function as static , but other wise it will not 
work, i want to know is there any  method   for calling a non-static c# function from aspx page 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360253/call-non-static-method-in-server-sideaspx-cs-from-client-side-use-javascript?lq=1 (and may others)

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay .but it will not work in my program

Answer (score 1):

There are no possibility to run function from aspx page directly via url.

Try the following:

1. Change your ajax request as below:

   ```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'About.aspx',
        data: '{"method":"updatingdatabase","username":"' + col1 + '","password":"' + col2 + '","age":"' + col3 + '","city":"' + col4 + '","id":"' + idlast + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                         var x = data.d;// i am trying to store the return data into a local variable

        },
        error: function (e) {

        }
    });
   ```
2. Update `Page_Load` handler in your page:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["method"]) && String.Compare(Request["method"], "updatingdatabase", true) == 0)
       {
           UpdatingDatabase(); //run the method
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
data: '{"method":"updatingdatabase","username":"' + col1 + '","password":"' + col2 + '","age":"' + col3 + '","city":"' + col4 + '","id":"' + idlast + '"}',
```

instead of

```
 url: 'About.aspx',
     data: '{"method":"updatingdatabase","username":"' + col1 + '","password":"' + col2 + '","age":"' + col3 + '","city":"' + col4 + '","id":"' + idlast + '"}',
```

and call function in pageload